# How to convert Word doc file into PDF

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 5.5 how we can convert word doc file into PDF. I am using phpoffice/phpword module to covert HTML to word doc any idea how we can convert word doc into pdf.

Comment: are you want to convert html in to pdf?

Comment: so like scraping a page and then storing in a PDF?

Comment: No I already have word doc files in application but only for download that content I need to convert them into PDF format.

Comment: Hope this article help future users: https://www.scratchcode.io/how-to-convert-word-to-pdf-in-laravel/

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution to convert Word Doc file into PDF in Laravel application.
I have installed phpoffice/phpword and dompdf/dompdf packages.

```
  public function getWordtoPDF(){    
     $domPdfPath = base_path('vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');

    //Load word file
    $Content = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load(public_path('TempDownload/Test.docx')); 

    //Save it into PDF
    $PDFWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($Content,'PDF');
    $PDFWriter->save('result3.pdf'); 
    exit;
   }
```

Comment: Actually requirement was like for few group of users content upload and download should be in word doc format but there is one another users group they can only download and see content of that document so for that I have to convert that file into PDF then download for user. We are not saving those pdf files in application level that is only for download purpose.